# Querying mongodb with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to fetch a document, update it and save it back to the db but it does not seem to be working i.e is not being saved to the db even though the result from the callback indicates that the update is successful by returning the newly updated document but on checking the db, the old version is still there. here is the query;

```
updateBed: (req, res) => {
    Client.findById(
        req.body.cid, (e, client) => {
            if (e) {
                console.log(e)
            } else {
                console.log(client.departments[2].beds[req.body.bedNo])
                client.departments.forEach((d, i) => {
                    if (d.name !== 'GOPD') {
                        return
                    } else {
                        d.beds[req.body.bedNo] = true
                    }
                })
                client.save((e, cl) => {
                    if (e) {
                        console.log(e)
                    } else {
                        console.log(cl.departments[2].beds[req.body.bedNo])
                        res.send(cl.departments)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
}
```

the first loggin before updating which is

```
console.log(client.departments[2].beds[req.body.bedNo])
```

differs from the last loggin after updating which is

```
console.log(cl.departments[2].beds[req.body.bedNo])
```

indicating that the update was saved but checking the db, am still seing the old version of the document. what am i missing here please

Comment: ` console.log(cl.departments[2].beds[req.body.bedNo])` is showing you the updated result?

Comment: yes but the changes is applied to the database

Answer (score 1):

```
client.save((e,cl)=> ....)
```

save method has only `e (error)` in callback.

Also your database structure is poorly written.
Most of your updates must be done by mongodb but not on your node server.

Make beds as a separate collection and give its id in client.department.

Make the following changes

```
client.save( e => {if(e) console.log(e)} )
```

Also findById is fine, but using findOne({_id : req.body.cid}) is better.

To check if it updated just **console.log(client)**.